# Understand python3 nested context managers

Tags: python-3.x, nested, contextmanager

I have a class:

```
class OuterCtxManager:
  def __enter__(self): 
    print('Outer enter')
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print('Outer exit')
```

When I do this:

```
def test_func():
  return OuterCtxManager()

with test_func() as context_manager:
  print('context_manager')
```

It prints:

```
Outer enter
context_manager
Outer exit
```

Why does it print `Outer enter` and `Outer exit` at all despite using context manager on already created object in a function? (rather than direct usage when creating an object like `with OuterCtxManager() as ocm`)

Interesting things come next:

When I do:

```
def test_func():
  first_object = OuterCtxManager()
  second_object = OuterCtxManager()
  return [first_object, second_object]

with test_func() as context_manager:
  print('context_manager')
```

It raises:

> AttributeError: **enter**

And in the end, when I do this:

```
class OuterCtxManager:
  def __init__(self):
    self.inner_ctx = InnerCtxManager()
  def __enter__(self): 
    print('Outer enter')
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print('Outer exit')

class InnerCtxManager:
  def __init__(self):
    print('inner_created')
  def __enter__(self): 
    print('Inner enter')
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print('Inner exit')


def test_func():
  first_object = OuterCtxManager()
  return first_object

with test_func() as context_manager:
  print('context_manager')
```

It prints:

```
inner_created
Outer enter
context_manager
Outer exit
```

I don't get any errors. Neither I get `Inner created` and `Inner enter`. Why is that so?

[Sandbox](https://repl.it/repls/NavajowhiteObviousFilename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it print Outer enter and Outer exit at all despite using context manager on already created object in a function?

The `with` statement you define says that python should call `__enter__` before the content of the `with` statement is executed and `__exit__` after that.

It doesn't matter if the object has allready been initialized. The with statement is going to call `__enter__` and `__exit__` anyway

> It raises `AttributeError: enter`

As you are returning a tuple and the tuple doesn't contain a definition of `__enter__` this error is thrown.

> I don't get any errors. Neither I get Inner created and Inner enter. Why is that so?

You don't get any errors because you use the `with` statement correctly with your `OuterCtxManager` and you don't get the output `Inner enter` and `Inner exit` because you don't use the `with` statement on the `InnerCtxManager` type.

Comment: Why does it print Outer enter and Outer exit at all despite using context manager on already created object in a function? (e.g. not like `with OuterCtxManager() as ocm`)

Comment: @trthhrtz basicly it doesn't matter if the object has allready been initialized. The `with` statement is going to call `__enter__`  and `__exit__` anyway.

Comment: That's what I've been missing